# Alert not working at given argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am designing a simple test cases for no.of.moves left. All the output is fine and the problem is with the alert, as the alert giving at 8 instead of 9. below is the small code i have done so far.

[FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXg2f/)

```
<div id="Moves">Moves Left : 10</div>
<button id="one" type="button" >Test1</button>



var MovesLeft = 10;

$("button").click(function () {

        if ( MovesLeft == 9) {
        alert("No Moves Left");
    }

$("#Moves").text("Moves Left : " + --MovesLeft );

});
```

Comment: thats b.c your decrementing BELOW the if(movesleft== 9... , move the `$("#Moves").text...` above the if statement and below the button on click

Comment: Just try to help others instead of giving negative marks i.e., question is not useful

Comment: @user3622856: If you want to complain about behaviour on SO, how about *posting a question and not hanging around to provide feedback on answers*. That makes us feel we are wasting time *trying to help others* :)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you do not want the counter to go below 9. Stick the update in an else condition:

```
var MovesLeft = 10;

$("button").click(function () {

    if (MovesLeft == 9) {
        alert("No Moves Left");
    } else {
        $("#Moves").text("Moves Left : " + --MovesLeft);
    }
});
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/nXg2f/3/

*PS. this question makes very little sense* :)